# How to DELETE a row with a GUID Value in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, guid

I have a column in SQLite of GUID type, I have tried a query like this, and it returns no error, but the row is not deleted

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Id='4ffbd580-b17d-4731-b162-ede8d698e026';
```

In SQLite Browser the Id values look like binary values, they have strange characters.

I also have tried this, but still does not work

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Id='{4ffbd580-b17d-4731-b162-ede8d698e026}';
```

Comment: You can get the proper SQL expression for this value with `SELECT quote(Id) FROM MyTable`. What does it return?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late for this, but it might just be useful for someone with the same problem.

I have a uniqueidentifier type of column in one of my tables and when I execute a select query without any conditions, it returns the result guid column values in this format -

{000B6A69-04D6-C557-7EA3-08CF8C8AD84B}

(Yes, with the braces)

I found out using typeof() function that my guid column values had been stored as text. So, I just tried out four different statements and luckily, **the 4th one worked** -

```
    1. select myGuidColumn, typeof(myGuidColumn) from MyTable WHERE [myGuidColumn] = '000B6A69-04D6-C557-7EA3-08CF8C8AD84B' --didn't work
    2. select myGuidColumn, typeof(myGuidColumn) from MyTable WHERE [myGuidColumn] = '{000B6A69-04D6-C557-7EA3-08CF8C8AD84B}' --didn't work
    3. select myGuidColumn, typeof(myGuidColumn) from MyTable WHERE [myGuidColumn] LIKE '{000B6A69-04D6-C557-7EA3-08CF8C8AD84B}' --didn't work
    4. select myGuidColumn, typeof(myGuidColumn) from MyTable WHERE [myGuidColumn] LIKE '000B6A69-04D6-C557-7EA3-08CF8C8AD84B' --it works!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command.  `Id` is a  probably a binary blob field

```
 DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Id= X'4ffbd580b17d4731b162ede8d698e026';
```

Comment: If I try this query in SQLite Browser it blocks completely and becomes unresponsive. it does not work.