# Entity Framework Core ExecuteSqlCommand delete with SQLite does not work

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have the following model:

```
public class LogData
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I use *Entity Framework Core* to save those models to an *SQLite* database, it works well.

I need to delete from the data (it is dynamic,  I can't use objects), so I use the following command:

```
string command="DELETE FROM LogData WHERE ID IN ('ea53b72a-4ab2-4f88-8f1d-0f96baa7cac7')";
context.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand(command);
```

According to the SQLite [syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html), it is valid.

Unfortunately, as a result I get back 0, so no row was affected.
When I remove the `WHERE` condition, *it deletes the contents of the table*.

I have a guessing that as the key column is a `Guid` and it is stored as a `BLOB`, the plain SQLite engine can't find it.

So I tried to alter the command to this:

```
string command="DELETE FROM LogData WHERE HEX(ID) IN ('ea53b72a-4ab2-4f88-8f1d-0f96baa7cac7')";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
```

Also tried this:

```
string command="DELETE FROM AuditLog WHERE HEX(ID) = 'ea53b72a-4ab2-4f88-8f1d-0f96baa7cac7'";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
```

This, too:

```
string command="DELETE FROM AuditLog WHERE ID = 'ea53b72a-4ab2-4f88-8f1d-0f96baa7cac7'";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
```

None of those helped.

What should I do about this?

Comment: First of all, why is the ID stored as a BLOB? can you switch it to a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER instead? Also what does the data look like after being saved? You might be running to this issue described here https://neosmart.net/blog/2018/converting-a-binary-blob-guid-to-text-in-sql/

Comment: @DavidG I get an exception if I use that: `SQLite Error 1: 'unrecognized token: "X'ea53b72a-4ab2-4f88-8f1d-0f96baa7cac7'"`

Comment: `context.SaveChanges();` ?

Comment: @DavidG Still not working :(

Comment: Nothing is deleted.

Comment: @Nestor have you tried `context.SaveChanges();`?

Comment: OK, this might seen odd, but does this delete your row: `WHERE ID = X'2ab753eab24a884f8f1d0f96baa7cac7'`?

Comment: @Mihai As the script works without the `WHERE` condition: yes, it is persisted to the database.

Comment: There seems to be a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740827/how-to-delete-a-row-with-a-guid-value-in-sqlite) but not any useful answer.. they say it works with `like` clause

Comment: @DavidG It gets deleted if I use that completely different ID... Why does THAT work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUIDs are stored in the database as a binary `BLOB` meaning you need to pass in a binary value to compare against. To do this you use the `X'...'` notation. Additionally, you need to convert the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the GUID to little endian. Fortunately, there's a handy extension method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17168469/1663001) to do your conversion:

```
public static Guid FlipEndian(this Guid guid)
{
    var newBytes = new byte[16];
    var oldBytes = guid.ToByteArray();

    for (var i = 8; i < 16; i++)
        newBytes[i] = oldBytes[i];

    newBytes[3] = oldBytes[0];
    newBytes[2] = oldBytes[1];
    newBytes[1] = oldBytes[2];
    newBytes[0] = oldBytes[3];
    newBytes[5] = oldBytes[4];
    newBytes[4] = oldBytes[5];
    newBytes[6] = oldBytes[7];
    newBytes[7] = oldBytes[6];

    return new Guid(newBytes);
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
//The source GUID
var source = Guid.Parse("ea53b72a-4ab2-4f88-8f1d-0f96baa7cac7");
//Flip the endianness
var flippedGuid = source.FlipEndian();

//Create the SQL
var command = $"DELETE FROM AuditLog WHERE ID = X'{flippedGuid.ToString().Replace("-", "")}'";

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
```

Comment: @Thanks, it really works :) I had no idea and could never find it out. I accept it as the answer.